# Minimize latency when downloading through asp.net web api and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a [web api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx), hosted on IIS, that returns a 4MB memory buffer through the [StreamContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.streamcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) class.

```
public class RestPerfController : ApiController
{
    byte[] data = new byte[4 * 1024 * 1024]; // 4MB

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(data))
        };
    }
}
```

I also have .net client running on another machine that `GET`s the data 128 times in a loop and calculates average latency.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[FourMB];

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
    {
        // Create the request
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://<IpAdddress>/RestPerfController/") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;

        // Start the timer
        timer.Restart();

        // Download the response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        long bytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, FourMB);
        }
        while (bytesRead > 0);

        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

The client and server are connected through a 10Gbps LAN.

Using default settings, the client sees an average latency of **90ms**.

Then I changed the server code to use [PushStreamContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.pushstreamcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of `StreamContent`

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
                Content = //new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(data))
                    new PushStreamContent(async (s, hc, tc) =>
                    {
                        await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                        s.Close();
                    },
                    "application/octet-stream")
           };
```

This caused the average latency on the client to drop from 90ms to **50ms**

Why is `PushStreamContent` almost twice as fast as `StreamContent`?
Is there a way of reducing the latency even further on the client? 50ms too seems pretty high for a 4MB transfer on a 10 Gigabit LAN.

EDIT: When I used http instead of https, the latency dropped from 50ms to 18ms. So it appears a large part of the latency was coming from the use of https.

Next, I did another experiment using [ntttcp](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/NTttcp-Version-528-Now-f8b12769)
Server: `ntttcp.exe -r -m 1,*,<ipaddress> -rb 2M -a 2 -t 15`
Client: `ntttcp.exe -s -m 1,*,<ipaddress> -l 4M -a 2 -t 15`

This showed an average latency of **11.4ms** for 4MB transfers. This I believe is the fastest I can get from tcp.

Since I am constrained to use https, I am interested in knowing if there are ways to bring down the 50ms latency.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to work with less buffer than 4Mb? I think it´s too large and may cause some system bottleneck. Remember that, at this rate, some VIRTUAL/PAGE operations may occurr if RAM is not available. Try something like 32kb-256Kb.

The problem may be not in the LAN itself but in the Windows to manage data at this rate.

The PushStreamContent forces the system to transmit the buffer, stoping some other activities - a kind of HIGH PRIORITY at streams.  The problem is about som error than can be occurr of the Stream is not well aligned/complete (the data itself).

Another problem is related to network checks are performed internally by StreamContent and not performed by PushStreamContent. As the name says, you´re forcing the communication (a kind of transmit anyway order).

Comment: I tried working with 128K buffers; this reduces latency to 2ms but overall data transfer rate is slower than with 4M buffers. With 4M buffers, half a gigabyte was transferred in 6s. With 128K buffers, it took 14s to transfer that data. With 256K buffers, half gig was transferred in 10s.

Comment: Did you tried 1Mb instead 4Mb?  Remember: you may balance your LAN rate with RAM requirements of WIndows to avoid SWAP ops.

Comment: Using 1MB buffer on server, half a gigabyte was transferred in 8s. Close to the 4MB buffer test but not better.

Comment: You are really near from the *real* possible transfer rate. If you consider that the nominal transfer for 4Mb in a 10Gb LAN sould be 20ms - and that rate is nominal, I mean, very rare to get in real life due to cable conditions,  temperature of cable and equipments, and so forth - I believe that, using an Async method via Push you´re in the practical best rate. As I said, you must consider the OS time slice to other of its functions.

Comment: 10Gbps = 1280 MBps, which implies 4MB should be transferred in 3.125ms

Comment: Ops! Yes @tcb, I was betrayed by my beer in that math...  :)

Comment: No such thing as high priority streams !?!? or additional network checks. 
There is nothing special about ``PushStreamContent`` versus ``StreamContent`` apart from more manual control over writing the data into the output stream. Check the code with a decompiler. It's so simple it'll make you cry.